# ThreadLocal<T> and static approach?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, clr

Static fields are being accessed using the class name like this:

```
public class Me()
{ 
  public static int a=5;
}
```

I can access it with `Me.a`, so it is attached to the *class*.

But when I look at:

```
static ThreadLocal<int> _x = new ThreadLocal<int> (() => 3);
```

It guarantees that each thread sees different copy of `_x`.

Didn't we just see that `static` is per *class* and not per *thread*? How does `ThreadLocal` manage to give each thread a different copy of `_x`?

Comment: What's up with your crazy formatting, spacing and capitalization? Please take a minute to clean up your post, and perhaps also make it a bit more concise.

Comment: You'll only have one `_x` per class, but that `ThreadLocal<T>` instance maintains a different value for each thread.

Comment: @Lee yeah , thanks, but how dows he do that ?it still marked as static...

Comment: @RoyiNamir - So your question is how does `ThreadLocal<T>` work?

Comment: @lee ive been showing what i know , and what is new to me ( static per thread ????) so yeah , generally thisis the final question

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You don't have a static variable per thread. You have one static `ThreadLocal<T>` instace which contains a value of type `T` for each thread.

Comment: @HansPassant I dont know if you looked at my profile pic , which has a picture all the books im reading ( each day something else)  , also , ALL my questions in this site are from c# in nutshell book and c# in depth. (parts which i dont understand), so the _read books_ part is irrelevant to me. it could be that i dont express myself as i should. e.g. I meant that static fields are accessed by class name as "attached to the class" . thats all. but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Didnt we just see that static is per class and not per thread ?

Yes. So imagine that a `ThreadLocal<T>` instance holds a `static Dictionary<Thread, T>` that looks up the Value for the current thread.

That is probably not how it actually works but it's a simple explanation of how it's possible. You could write it yourself.

So you still have only 1 static `_x`. But `_x.Value` can be bound to anything, like the courrent Thread.

Comment: But still , the class has a _static_ field , so it must have its static field. - you idea is a way of solving this , if there has been some kind of proxy mechanism. but we didnt use it we actually used basic keyword _static_....am i right ?\

Comment: `static` is enough. There only needs to be 1 dictionary shared by all threads.

Comment: oh,,,, so youre saying that the dictionarry itself is static....well, very interesting

Comment: Yes, you still only have 1 static `_x`. But `_x.Value` can be bound to anything.

Comment: (not related much) But does instance fields ( non static) are seen by other threads ? and if they do , why Do I need to make those fields _static_ ?

Comment: Hmm.... Yes, they can be seen by others threads. But you do not (usually) have to make them static.

Comment: @Royi If you're interested in how thread locals are usually implemented. Under Windows, we have a TIB (Thread information block) per thread that contains information such as stack ranges, thread id, etc. Thread local data is stored in a table whose address is itself stored in the TIB. So your "static field" is basically a pointer to `TIB+something`, the only difference between threads is that `TIB` has a different value for each (the TIB address is usually stored in FS).

Answer (score 8):

The reference `_x` will indeed be one per class, as per its `static` specifier. However, only the reference will be shared among all threads, not the value inside its object. When you access `_x.Value`, `ThreadLocal<T>` invokes system-specific code that provides storage on the current thread, and reads or writes to that thread-specific storage.

Answer (score 4):

My C# isn't that great, so here's a C++ answer to the same effect: Imagine a hypothetical class that contains a large array:

```
class Foo
{
    int array[HUGE];
    int & get() { return array[this_thread_id()]; }
}:
```

Now you can have one single, global (or class-static) object:

```
Foo tlstorage;
```

To access it from anywhere you say `tlstorage.get() = 12;`. However, the data is stored in the slot that "belongs" to your current thread. The *entire* storage is global, but only one slice is exposed to each thread.

Other languages like C and C++ have native support for this concept, and when you decorate a global or static variable as "thread-local", the compiler builds something that amounts to the same effect automatically. Perhaps in C# this is a library feature, though it probably also maps to something intrinsic.